# Регулярка для видео с VK

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Собственно поделитесь регуляркой, с помощью которой можно будет вытащить через preg_match() id пользователя (цифры ДО знака *) и id видео (цифры ПОСЛЕ знака* ). 
Ссылка на видео может быть двух видов:  http://vk.com/video-39542227_162571485
 http://vk.com/video39542227_162571485.  
  Вот что у меня пока что получилось написать:

```
$str = '/(vk\.com|m\.vk\.com|)\/(video)()/i';
$res = preg_match($str, 'http://vk.com/video6596116_168597909', $match);
```

Comment: С чего это? Я просто регулярки не знаю. Простые еще могу писать, но с посложнее беда начинается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_match('/video([\d]+)_(\d+)/i', 'http://vk.com/video6596116_168597909', $matches) && print_r($matches);

Array
(
    [0] => video6596116_168597909
    [1] => 6596116
    [2] => 168597909
)
```

Comment: Это, само собой, круче API.

Comment: вот это что ли <https://vk.com/pages.php?o=-1&p=video.get> ?

Comment: Если ссылка будет такой: http://vk.com/video-39542227_162571485, то не будет вхождения из-за знака минус.

Answer (score 0):

Так можно получить id для записей на стене, видео и фото, причем с "-", если это необходимо:

```
(?:wall|video|photo)?(.([\d]+)_(\d+))
```

Comment: А точка там зачем?

Comment: Из [документации](https://vk.com/dev/video.get) `Обратите внимание, идентификатор сообщества в параметре owner_id необходимо указывать со знаком "-" — например, owner_id=-1 соответствует идентификатору сообщества` Без точки не будет учета "-". Вот отличный ресурс для написания регулярных выражений [http://rubular.com/](http://rubular.com/)

Comment: Я умею писать регулярки. Но почему там не `-?`, а `.` - ведь точка ещё и одну цифру сожрёт, если минуса не будет, а она находится вне захватываемой группы.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Я попробовал `(?:wall|video|photo)?(-?([\d]+)_(\d+))` и `(?:wall|video|photo)?(.([\d]+)_(\d+))` для https://vk.com/videos-999?z=video-999_999
https://vk.com/videos-999?z=video999_999 работают одинаково.

Comment: Если видео не принадлежит сообществу: `https://vk.com/videos99999999?z=video99999999_999999999%2Fpl_99999999_-9` (в реальной ссылке поменял все цифры на девятки).