# Регулярные выражения. preg_replace

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день. Новичек в регулярных выражениях, но хочу разобраться. 
Есть строка, ее нужно привести к одному виду, т.е. оставить только название.
Варианты:
http://vk.com/id62334653
vk.com/id62334653
id62334653
и т.д.

Когда работаю с значением:

```
$data = 'http://vk.com/id62334653';

 $pattern = '/((http(s)?:\/\/)?(new\.)?(m\.)?(vk\.com\/)?)([a-z_0-9.]*)?(.*)?/ius';
$data = preg_replace($pattern, '[$7]', trim($data)); 
echo '<br />'.$data2.'='.$data;
```

Нет проблем, результат:
http://vk.com/id62334653=[id62334653]

Но если строка:

```
$data = 'Михаил Успенский http://vk.com/m.uspenskiy';
```

результат:
Михаил Успенский [m.uspenskiy]

Посоветовали сделать вот так:

```
$pattern = '/((http(s)?:\/\/)?(new\.)?(m\.)?(vk\.com\/)?)([a-z_0-9.]*)?(.*)?/ius';
$data = preg_replace($pattern, '[$7]', trim($data)); 
echo '<br />'.$data2.'='.$data;
```

Но проблема в том, что тут выдается вообще пустая строка
если мы убираем знак "?" после (http(s)?://) , то все в порядке, но тогда выражения типа "vk.com/m.uspenskiy" не проходят, т.к. в нем нет "http" , но этот вариант ввода также возможнен.

Вопрос, как учесть все эти данные ? т.е. как учесть варианты:  "vk.com/m.uspenskiy"  и 'Михаил Успенский http://vk.com/m.uspenskiy' , чтобы был результат "m.uspenskiy"?

Comment: потому что ваш паттерн совпадает с http://vk.com/m.uspenskiy' а $7 соотвествует m.uspenskiy, вот урл и заменяется. А "Михаил Успенский " никуда не добавляется, а просто присуствует в исходной строке

Comment: Может вам поможет http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/322551/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE-%D1%81-vk

Comment: чтобы легче разобраться с регулярками, советую http://regex101.com , особенно там есть пункт "regex debugger" - показывает пошагово, как обработчик понял ваш паттерн.

Answer (score 2):

Вы находите в полной строке (`Михаил Успенский http://vk.com/m.uspenskiy`)  подстроку по указанному паттерну (`http://vk.com/m.uspenskiy`) и заменяете ее на ее же часть (`[m.uspenskiy]`). Так и получается.

Если вам нужно получить искомую часть в отедельной переменной, нужно использовать что-то типа такого:

```
$data = 'Михаил Успенский http://vk.com/m.uspenskiy';

$pattern = '/((http(s)?:\/\/)(new\.)?(m\.)?(vk\.com\/)?)(?P<id>.*)?/ius';
preg_match($pattern, $data, $matches);

$id = isset($matches['id']) ? $matches['id'] : '';

echo '<br />'.$data.'='.$id;
```

`preg_match` грубо говоря, разбирает входную строку на части согласно паттерну и вы можете получить каждую найденную часть отдельно.

Обратите внимание, что я добавил `?P<id>` внутри скобок в той части регулярки, которую я хочу видеть в `$matches['id']`. Это позволяет спокойно менять регулярку не привязываясь к индексу группы.

Comment: Спасибо, но  "Михаил Успенский http://vk.com/m.uspenskiy" для  "$pattern = '/((http(s)?:\/\/)?(new\.)?(m\.)?(vk\.com\/)?)([a-z_0-9.]*)?(.*)?/ius';"   не подходит, т.к. выдается пустая строка.

Comment: т.е. не как учесть варианты:  "vk.com/m.uspenskiy"  и 'Михаил Успенский http://vk.com/m.uspenskiy'

Comment: @максим конечно можно. Я предложил вам вариант с учетом конкретной регулярки. Если вы изменили регулярку - разумеется, он не подходит. Прочитайте как работает preg_match и все поймёте. Я в своем коде брал подстроку 7, найденную регуляркой. Вам нужно изменить цифру. или немного доработать регулярку до универсального варианта. Я сейчас не могу дать конкретный код, позже - возможно.

Comment: @Максим147 дополнил ответ.

Comment: @Максим147 окончательны ответ вам подошел?